# GWCategories + Stash

Tags: categories, stash, gwcode-categories, nested-list, mustash

I'm using GwCategories to get all subcategories from a certain parent category (in this case, main_cat_id). Within this list, I'm adding a nested list, training_list_{cat_id}.

In my template, I can see the categories listed, but the nested list shows nothing. Now, I know that one of the subcategories has the ID 60. I replace {cat_id} in the example below by a hard-coded 60, the list does show. So I'm having a bit of a parsing issue here, I guess.

This is my (somewhat stripped) code:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="categories_list" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:gwcode_categories custom_fields="yes" channel="channel" cat_id="{main_cat_id}" depth="2"}
        {stash:category_name}{cat_name}{/stash:category_name}
        {stash:category_id}{cat_id}{/stash:category_id}

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="training_list_{cat_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
            {exp:channel:entries channel="channel" dynamic="no" category="{cat_id}"}
                {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
                {stash:title}{title} - {cat_id}{/stash:title}
            {/exp:channel:entries}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
    {/exp:gwcode_categories}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a parse order issue, you may need to add `parse="inward"` to your nested `set_list`. Using this means that it will parse the variable in your `name` parameter early on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `parse_depth="2"` to the outermost set_list tag.

This is required so that both the gwcode_categories tag and the inner set_list tag are parsed *before* the outermost set_list captures it's row data.

As per example here:
https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Lists#three-and-more-dimensional-lists